Twilio is calling both static and dynamic webhooks
I have a twilio number setup for my application. Messaging service URL is configured to call one of my application's static API endpoints when a new message received. Once a new message received, I'm creating a twilio conversation and creating a dynamic webhook using the unique conversation id. So, any new messages to this conversation should call my dynamic webhook url only which is another API endpoint in my application. The problem is, Twilio is calling both the dynamic webhook url and static webhook url when a new message received to the existing conversation. Is there any way to limit this and callback only the dynamic webhook url when a new reply for a particular conversation?
